# Friendship Theorem: Finding a simple proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, graph-theory

I'm working with a first-year professor for a Discrete Mathematics course at my university, and we're trying to come up with a proof for the friendship theorem that's simple enough to show and explain to a group of students just a few weeks into graph theory lectures. We believe it's possible to find one, we just haven't had any luck by ourselves and the ones online all appear to be a bit too complex. Does anyone here have a simple proof or can outline how we could approach finding one?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Perhaps, giving an example of a couple of approaches that you deem too complicated might save time and help readers give you useful answers.

Comment: For the reader who is casually glancing past, the Friendship Theorem can be stated as "Any two members of a certain College have a unique common enemy who is also a member of the College. Show that there is some College member (the ‘Junior Bursar’) who is everyone else’s enemy."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you have already examined the proof in [*Proofs from THE BOOK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK) by [Martin Aigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Aigner) and [Günter M. Ziegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnter_M._Ziegler) (Chapter 29 in the first edition, Chapter 39 in the fourth edition) and are looking for something a little different.

The Wikipedia article ["Friendship graph"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph) cites a paper by Craig Huneke, [The friendship theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2695332?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), *Amer. Math. Monthly* 109 (February 2002), 192-194, in which the author presents not one but two simple proofs of the so-called friendship theorem. In an added note (*Amer. Math. Monthly* 110 (January 2003), 79) Huneke acknowledges that the first of his two proofs was published earlier by Judith Q. Longyear and T. D. Parsons, [The friendship theorem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725872900637), *Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A* 75 = *Indag. Math.* 34 (1972), 257-262.

You can find several proofs (including a version of the Longyear–Parsons proof) online in ["A Survey on The Friendship Theorem"](http://www.academia.edu/9846630/A_Survey_on_The_Friendship_Theorem) by Debashis Chatterjee.

Comment: The first proof by Huneke is almost exactly what we were looking for! Thank you!